How to kill hanging processes when exiting MS Visual Code on remote server?
Is there a setting in Visual Code that will force the processes (On remove Linux server) to exit when the editor is closed? I'm using the SSH-Remote plugin to develop on the remote server. The only setting is to do it manually via command: "Remote-SSH: Uninstall VS Code Server from Host..."
I manually ran the command "Remote-SSH: Uninstall VS Code Server from Host..." each time, but I would like to set it up to automatically do it at the editor exit if possible.
